# find Minimum window substring - leetcode - Solution not working

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Question :https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/

Given a string S and a string T, find the minimum window in S which will contain all the characters in T in complexity O(n).

Example:

Input: S = "ADOBECODEBANC", T = "ABC"
Output: "BANC"

I tried hard to come up with solution using sliding window technique but I'm stuck here. Can some please help?

```
    package com.tryPrep.Strings;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MinWindowSubstring {

    static String minWinSubStr(String s, String t){

        HashMap<Character, Integer> tabl = new HashMap<>();

        for(char c: t.toCharArray()){
            int charCount=0;
            if(tabl.containsKey(c))
              charCount = tabl.get(c);
            tabl.put(c, charCount+1);
        }

        int begin =0, end =0, counter=tabl.size();

        String ans="";
        int max=s.length();
        while(end < s.length()) {

            char endChar = s.charAt(end);
            if (tabl.containsKey(endChar)) {
                int charCount = tabl.get(endChar);
                if (charCount > 0) {
                    counter--;
                    tabl.put(endChar, charCount - 1);
                }
            }
            end++;

            while (counter == 0) {

                if (max > end - begin) {
                    ans = s.substring(begin, end - begin);
                    max = ans.length();
                }

                char beginChar = s.charAt(begin);
                if (tabl.containsKey(beginChar)) {
                    int charCount = tabl.get(beginChar);
                    if(charCount == 0) {
                        tabl.put(beginChar, charCount + 1);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

                begin++;
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "ADOBECODEBANC";
        String t = "ABC";

        System.out.println("minWinSubStr M1 : " + minWinSubStr(s, t));

    }
}
```

Output :

```
minWinSubStr M1 : ADOBEC
```

I see the loop gets satisfied when end reaches the string length but the counter is still not 0 here. Can you please point me what is the issue to unblock me?

Comment: Can you please explain what's the logic used? It's hard to comprehend anything without the author's explanation.

Comment: In this problem, you have to continuously keep looking characters and accommodate them. But, you also have to try to shrink the window at each index by checking if shrinking makes the window less sumptuous or is it exactly satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you incremented your counter after deleting the A (at index 0). You start finding another A to compensate for that loss.

```
ADOBECODEBANC
 ^        ^
begin    end
```

> When you are doing that, unknowingly your code did not take B (at index 9) into account and end pointer reached A (at index 10).

Afterward when begin pointer reached B (at index 4) and you incremented counter, your end pointer was not able to find any other B.

```
ADOBECODEBANC
    ^     ^
  begin  end
```

Hence you got the answer as **ADOBEC**

> What you could do to correct that when end pointer finds any character which must be accounted, remove the first index of that character and add the one encountered recently.
>
> Once that done you could easily ignore that character when begin pointer encounters it as the frequency of that character wouldn't affect.
>
> This is valid since we want to shrink window from the beginning, not from the end.

In your case, you could decrease the counter every time the end pointer encounters any character in **tabl**.

Now when the begin pointer encounters any character whose value is in negative don't increment the counter, simply do the plus one in value.

Also, you should print values from begin to end.
`s.substring(begin, end)`

Think that on the case when begin = 8 and end = 10
`s.substring(8, 10), not s.substring(8, 2)`

```
static String minWinSubStr(String s, String t) {
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(t);

    HashMap<Character, Integer> tabl = new HashMap<>();

    for (char c : t.toCharArray()) {
        int charCount = 0;
        if (tabl.containsKey(c))
            charCount = tabl.get(c);
        tabl.put(c, charCount + 1);
    }

    int begin = 0, end = 0, counter = tabl.size();

    String ans = "";
    int max = s.length();
    while (end < s.length()) {
        char endChar = s.charAt(end);
        if (tabl.containsKey(endChar)) {
            int charCount = tabl.get(endChar);
```

> ```
>             if (charCount > 0) {
>                 counter--;
>             }
>             tabl.put(endChar, charCount - 1);
> ```

```
        }
        end++;

        while (counter == 0) {
            if (max > end - begin) {
```

> ```
>                 ans = s.substring(begin, end);
> ```

```
                max = ans.length();
            }

            char beginChar = s.charAt(begin);
            if (tabl.containsKey(beginChar)) {
                int charCount = tabl.get(beginChar);
```

> ```
>                 if(charCount < 0) {
>                     tabl.put(beginChar, charCount + 1);
>                 }
>                 else if (charCount == 0) {
>                     tabl.put(beginChar, charCount + 1);
>                     counter++;
>                 }
> ```

```
            }

            begin++;
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Highlighted the part which I have changed.

> **Note**: This code solves only your use case and is **NOT supposed to give AC on all test-cases**.